# How can I query xml with javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

```
javascript:
(async () => {
    const rss = [
        'https://reddit.com/r/news.rss',
        /*
         'https://www.upwork.com/ab/feed/jobs/rss?api_params=1&amp;orgUid=424151849314844673&amp;paging=0%3B10&amp;q=title%3A%28cto%29&amp;securityToken=925852acb79387c67d921519fd18fed25f501cc940c417db8a53c2ee9530a5a4c9fb27ac83bd44992aaa39d2509a1aa6e7053c4795d714657bc4ac744b268718&amp;sort=recency&amp;userUid=424151849306456064&amp;user_location_match=1'
        */
    ];

    let htm = '<section id="feed">';

    rss.map(async feed => {
        console.log('feed', feed);

        let xml = '';

        try {
            const res = await fetch('https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url='+feed);
            xml = await res.text();
            console.log('xml', xml);
        } catch(err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        const node = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");
        const items = [...node.evaluate('//entry', node, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)];

        console.log('items: ', items);

        items.map(item => {
            const link = item.evaluate('link', item);
            const title = item.evaluate('title', item);

            console.log('link: ', link.evaluate('@href', link));
            console.log('title:', title.evalute('.', title));

            htm += `
            <div class="item">${link.evaluate('@href', link)} - ${title.evalute('.', title)}</div>
            `;
        });
    });

    htm += '</section>';
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htm);
})();
```

I get undefined for `title` and `link` and can't figure out why.

Comment: Small aside: you may find using something like [`fast-xml-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser) easier to work with. It converts the XML to JSON which is much more easy to manipulate. You can use it in the browser. (Not an advert.)

Comment: looking for vanilla js

Answer (score 0):

Just in terms of extracting `title` and `link`, I would tend to do it this way (which could probably be further simplified):

```
const items = node.evaluate('//entry', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

for(let i = 0; i < items.snapshotLength; i++) {
let entry = items.snapshotItem(i); 
  const link = node.evaluate('.//link/@href', entry,  null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  const title = node.evaluate('.//title', entry,  null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

  console.log(link.snapshotItem(0).textContent);    
  console.log(title.snapshotItem(0).textContent);   
}
```

The output should be the title and link for each of the 25 entries in the feed.

Comment: what is this `snapshotItem(0)`?

Comment: It's the first (and only, in this case) `snapshotItem`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult/snapshotItem

Comment: can i just do `//link[1]/@href/text()`?

Comment: @chovy With `ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE` the `[1]` in `//link` doesn't help you avoid having to use `snapshotItem(i)`. More importantly, `@href` is an attribute node and its attribute value doesn't have a `text()` child. With vanilla js, you have to extract the `@href` attribute value by using `textContent`.